# OperationalError : FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "fibzadmin", database "fibz", SSL off

Tags: python, django, postgresql, devops

I have been struggling with this issue for a few days now. I have read numerous other SO threads and it seems like my django app is having difficulty connecting to the postgres database. I am not sure why that is happening though. I am hoping some of the experts out there can take a look and tell me why this might be happening. I have pasted some of my configuration here.

This is what my settings.py contains

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'fibz',
        'USER':"fibzadmin",
        "PASSWORD":"fibzadmin",
        "HOST":"localhost",
        "PORT":"5432",
    }
}
```

This is what my pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf look like

```
sudo vim /var/lib/pgsql9/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Output:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             power_user      0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             other_user      0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             storageLoader   0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

following are the main uncommented lines

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432 
max_connections = 100
```

and this is from the psql

```
(fibzVenv) [admin]$ sudo su - postgres
Last login: Fri Nov 23 07:13:53 UTC 2018 on pts/3
-bash-4.2$ psql -U postgres
psql (9.2.24)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                              List of roles
 Role name  |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 fibzadmin |                                                | {}

postgres=# \l
                                     List of databases
   Name    |   Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |     Access privileges     
-----------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------
 postgres  | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 fibz      | fibzadmin  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/fibzadmin           +
           |            |          |             |             | fibzadmin=CTc/fibzadmin
 template0 | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres              +
           |            |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres              +
           |            |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

Are there any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong or what I should be looking at ? This is happening on amazon linux its on the same instance.

Comment: what's in the `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Also shouldn't `ENGINE` be set to `django.db.backends.postgresql` instead of `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis`.

Comment: No I am using postgis plugin instead of postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error message is very accurate. Looking at your pg_hba.conf I don't see a line specifying `fibzadmin` as a valid user except over ipv6.

I think you need to add the following line:

```
host    all             fibzadmin     0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Comment: I am going to try this.

Comment: after adding that I am getting the error FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "fibzadmin". Is there a simple way for me to check if the password I specified is correct ?

Comment: think you can assume that `password authentication failed` means the password you entered is incorrect. If you're testing things you could temperarely set the trust level as `trust` so you can log in.